# c# MVC Url format change automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, url

I'm having a little issue with my web application. I'm using C# MVC for my application and I have created an custom format for my URL because my application will connect to different database depending the code I receive in my URL.

The problem is when I first lunch my application, the url change along the way.
here's an example:

my custom format is like that:

> {code}/{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}

I have this url from the start:

> http://localhost:47730/efs/fr-ca

here **efs** mean **{code}** and **fr-ca** the **{culture}**

but along the way it become this

> http://localhost:47730/Home/Index

I want it to be like that:

> http://localhost:47730/efs/fr-ca/Home/Index

Here's my routeConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{code}/{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            //defaults: new { code = string.Empty,culture = string.Empty, controller = "Home", action = "RV", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


        routes.MapRoute("Error", "{*url}", new { controller = "Error", action = "Error" });
    }
}
```

If you need more information just ask me :)

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

> Try this

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{code}/{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                         defaults: new {code ="efs",culture="fr-ca", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


            routes.MapRoute("Error", "{*url}", new { controller = "Error", action = "Error" });
        }
    }
```

Comment: The thing is that the code "efs" can be anything so I don't want to put an default value there

Comment: Then, don't include the defaults. However, if there's no default, then you must *always* provide the portion of the URL. In other words, there would be no way to load just the document root (`/`). The main point of @Shan's answer, though, is that you need to change your default route to include these route parameters. If you have a route that does not require them, MVC will always short circuit the routing and go with the route that doesn't require them.